# Faster solution to conditional nested loop with grepl

Tags: r, performance

I have a dataset and two vectors. Vector "A" is a vector with patterns and vector 'B' is a vector with replacements.
I would like to go over Col2 in the datatable (dt), check it for precense of patterns in vector "A". And if so, write its replacement "B" to Col4.

For this, I wrote the following code:

```
A <- c("AA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD")
B <- c("PP","QQQ", "I", "Beep")
A <- paste("\\<",A, "\\>", sep = "")


  dt <- structure(list(Col1 = c(0L, 2L, 3L, 5L), Col2 = c("RR,BBB", 
     "S,AA", "FOO", "C"), Col3 = c(1L, 8L, 4L, 2L)), row.names = 
         c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")


for (i in 1:length(A)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(dt)){
    if(grepl(A[i], dt[j,2])){
      dt[j,4] <- B[i]
    }      
  }
}

This script works with the following result:

 Col1      Col2    Col3   Col4
  0     "RR,BBB"    1     "CCC"
  2      "S,AA"     8     "PP"
  3      "FOO"      4     <NA>
  5       "C"       2     <NA>
```

However, the since the dataset is about 400.000 rows and the pattern and replacement vector are in the thousands, it takes very long to run. How can I rewrite this code so its more efficient?

Comment: Please provide the data in a readable format, by providing us the `dput(head(data))` output and indicate which of the vectors is the pattern and which is the replacement.

Comment: Yeah, what is `dt`?

Comment: I get your loop on patterns but looping on the rows is unnecessary: `grepl` is vectorised and returns a logical vector which you can use to index your data.frame. Or use `grep` to get the matching indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to replace the complete string I think you need to use a different pattern.

```
A <- paste0('.*', A, '.*')
```

You can then use `str_replace_all` which is vectorized.

```
names(B) <- A
dt$Col4 <- stringr::str_replace_all(dt$Col2, B)
```

but if a pattern is not found it keeps the string as it is and you want to turn them to `NA` so :

```
dt$Col4[dt$Col2 == dt$Col4] <- NA
dt

#  Col1     Col2 Col3 Col4
#1    0 R por ke    1  chi
#2    2 Zoom,bee    8   aa
#3    3    om ie    4 <NA>
#4    5      vor    2   ky
```

**data**

```
dt <- structure(list(Col1 = c(0L, 2L, 3L, 5L), Col2 = c("R por ke", 
"Zoom,bee", "om ie", "vor"), Col3 = c(1L, 8L, 4L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
A <- c("bee", "por", "fa", "vor")
B <- c("aa","chi", "sti", "ky")
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak Shah, thats is indeed what I was looking for. I tested it and it works on one of my datasets. For the other it keeps returning the original column. Do you know why this might happen? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the pattern is correct. Test it on single value before testing it on single dataframe.